# Port confirguration for remote debugging multiple JVMs

Tags: java, remote-debugging

I have defined my remote debugging port in the Java Runtime variables but what is the behavior when multiple JVMs run on the same host with that configuration.

After the first instance takes that port will the other JVMs not be reachable or is there a fallback to determine another available port?

Is there any way to determine this port or configure additional ports to be used?

My Java Runtime Settings:

**-Xms64m -Xmx256m -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=58000,server=y,suspend=n**

[image: Eclipse settings]

Answer (score 1):

Every JVM needs a unique port number assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 debugger can attach on a single port. I do not see why you would need to debug simultaneously the same code many times, you will be confused.

What I would propose to you is:

1. Debug on first JVM
2. Once done, detach first JVM
3. Debug on 2nd JVM
   .....

Comment: The scenario is that I have two Applets running at the same time. This starts two JVMs and I am interested in the second JVM that doesn't have the debugging port open.

Comment: @OliverS How are you debugging?

Comment: Just Eclipse with remote target configuration.

Comment: @OliverS And what are you adding in your java program to tell it to debug on a certain port?

Comment: @OliverS Ok so both of your jvm have the same debug port which is 58000. What I mean is that both of your jvm have the line `-Xms64m -Xmx256m -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=58000,server=y,suspend=n`, correct?

Comment: Yes and that is my problem. Obviously only the first JVM has port 58000 the second has none.

Comment: @OliverS you can't choose a port per jvm? 58000 for the first and 58001 for the 2nd? I suspect you are using a client-server application where you wnat to debug the client and the server?

Comment: Nope that is a general configuration parameter for all JVMs.

Comment: @OliverS You cannot launch the jvms directly from eclipse?

Comment: The problem is when you fire off multiple (undetermined number) JVMs from a script, you simply cannot preassign a different number for each of them without a lot of jumping through hoops, so it would be nice to have a way to have this auto-increment.